# node build error: await server.init({env: process.env});

Tags: node.js, web, sveltekit

I built a website in SvelteKit and wanted to deploy it on an Ubuntu server, but when I run node build to start the server, I get this error message:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WUYW.png)

I'm really new to deploying websites on my own server, so i don't really know what to do

I know that i need to change something called adapter. So i searched it and found a guide in the SvelteKit docs in which they explained what you need to change in the svelte.config.js

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        csrf: {
            checkOrigin: false,
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

The csrf part is required because I had another error before this one

Comment: What are all the steps you followed? Provide more information

Comment: Can you provide some code so that we can determine the issue?

Comment: there is a related active discussion on the svelte discord: 
https://discord.com/channels/457912077277855764/1124723092040712333

it seems like there is a problem with the latest version of adapter-node. try using v1.2